# How to allow traffic from the network load balancer to an instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm following [Set Up Dynamic Port Mapping for Amazon ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/). However, I don't have permission to create an Application Load Balancer so the only choice is to create a Network Load Balancer.

How to allow traffic from the Network Load Balancer to an instance?

I'm creating the Network Load Balancer using the following code. The AWS console doesn't have the option to assign security group, while it does allow it for an Application Load Balancer.

```py
    elb = elb.create_load_balancer(
            Name=name,
            Subnets=[i['SubnetId'] for i in subnets],
            Scheme='internal',
            Type='network',
            IpAddressType='ipv4')['LoadBalancers'][0]

    target_group = elb.create_target_group(
            Name=target_group_name,
            Protocol='TCP',
            Port=4045,
            VpcId=main_vpc['VpcId'],
            HealthCheckProtocol='TCP',
            HealthCheckEnabled=True,
            HealthCheckIntervalSeconds=30,
            HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds=10,
            HealthyThresholdCount=3,
            UnhealthyThresholdCount=3,
            TargetType='instance',
        )['TargetGroups'][0]
```

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

Network Load Balancers do not use Security Groups.

Instead, **attach the appropriate Security Group to the target instance**. It will be used for incoming traffic.

This is one way in which a Network Load Balancer differs from an Application or Classic Load Balancer.